# Can't use let in webstorm

Tags: javascript, typescript, webstorm

I am studying typescript and I'm trying to create a simple let and it won't work because it says I need to use ECMA6 or higher. This is is the error message I'm getting in the typescript compiler:

> Error:(11, 5) TS1153: 'let' declarations are only available when targeting ECMAScript 6 and higher.

And this is the code:

```
class website{
  url:string;
  facebookLikes:number;
}


let google = new website(); 

google.url = "google.com";
google.facebookLikes = 23124;
```

I searched online and I found an answer that says to go to settings and langauges and frameworks and go to javascript and change it to EcmaScript6. I done this but I still get the same error.

If anyone can shed some light on this I would really appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: did you close and reopen the editor after changing settings? or at least cut all text and pasted it to trigger re-validation? just in case it was slow to notice the change in settings...

Comment: Ye I tried closing and reopening it but still same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `ES6` target just as the error suggests.
I don't know how you compile your typescript files, if it's using the builtin compiler or a file watcher, but in any case the [compiler options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) have the target property which should be `ES6` if you want to use `let` (and other es6 features).

If for example you are using `tsconfig.json` then it should look like this:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES6",
        ...
    }
}
```